# Create line chart from csv file without excel

Tags: csv, charts

Suppose i have the following data in csv format :

Time    Total   Allocated   Deallocated
0.00004 0   16  0
0.000516    16  31  0
0.046274    47  4100    0
0.047036    4147    0   31
0.047602    4116    35  0
0.214296    4151    4100    0
0.215109    8251    0   35

i am looking for some kind of software that will allow me to make a line chart of it ( where time column will be the X axis) , i used excel for now , but i am looking for something else,that will allow me to see in greater details .

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Datawrapper](http://datawrapper.de/). It's very easy and you can publish it on the web or export it to a PNG file.

Comment: Hi , my data set is big , around 9000 rows, its to slow for my needs . :\

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [R](http://cran.r-project.org/). Here is an example of code to generate a time series plot :

```
library("ggplot2")
df <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2012-01-01"),as.Date("2012-12-01"), by = "month"), x = rnorm(12))
ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y = x)) + geom_line() + theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but still: https://plot.ly is also a good site for that kind of stuff.